# O que é a "gibeira" e o "jiló" do caipira na "Romaria" do Renato Teixeira?

Tags: português-brasileiro, significado-em-contexto

O [Priberam diz que *gibeira*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/gibeira) é o mesmo que que ‘algibeira’ ou ‘bolso’ e o [*jiló*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/jil%C3%B3) é uma planta ou o seu fruto. Mas a canção dá a entender que a tal “gibeira” é algo distintivo de um certo modo de vida do caipira, não uma vulgar algibeira qualquer; e *jiló* parece ser figurado. Falo claro da canção [“Romaria” de Renato Teixeira](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aup_ZeTHtcI), com [letra aqui no *letras*](https://www.letras.mus.br/renato-teixeira/271363/) (vou confessar que foi a primeira vez que ouvi com atenção esta letra absolutamente fabulosa):

> É de sonho e de pó
> O destino de um só.
> Feito eu perdido em meus pensamentos sobre o meu cavalo.
> É de laço e de nó, de **gibeira**, o **jiló**
> Desta vida, cumprida a sol. [Ou “a só”?]
>
> Sou caipira, Pirapora, Nossa Senhora de Aparecida...

O [*letras*](https://www.letras.mus.br/renato-teixeira/271363/) diz que é “a sol”, que é o que eu ouço também [nesta interpretação da Elis Regina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwkjS_OXbX8), mas ouço “a só” [nesta do Almir Sater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30vGAwElGjg), o que confere com a letra no [*Letras Sertanejas*](http://letrassertanejas.com.br/musica/romaria/), que por outro lado diz que é “gibeira **ou** jiló”, que para mim não faz sentido; Na interpretação do [Renato Teixeira](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aup_ZeTHtcI) não tenho a certeza se é “a só” ou “a sol”. Mas “a só” eu compreendo; se for mesmo “a sol”, vou ter que fazer mais outra pergunta: significaria ‘ao sol’ ou ‘de sol a sol’ ou o quê?

Voltando à *gibeira* (só encontrei no Priberam), é claro que não é um bolso qualquer; deve ser algo que distingue o homem na história, tal como o laço e o nó. Mas o que é? E já agora, o que é o *jiló* naquele contexto? *Jiló* é uma planta e também o seu fruto [(Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/jil%C3%B3). Mas ali parece ter um sentido figurado. Dá a ideia que é metáfora para algo normalmente bom (mas o Priberam diz que é amargo), mas que no caso do nosso homem é simplesmente constituído de laço, nó e gibeira.

Comment: Quando comparo a letra de músicas em sites diferentes, por vezes me deparo com diferenças grosseiras e certamente uma das duas está errada. Ouvi as gravações e me parece que a vida é "cumprida a só" em ambas as gravações. Quanto ao "jiló", ele é um fruto muito amargo e "o jiló dessa vida" pode estar sendo usado como uma metáfora para "o amargor dessa vida".  São as minhas impressões.

Comment: Poderia ser "a só"  (sozinho) mas como existem regiões do Brasil onde o sol é escaldante, poderia "a sol"  significando "sob o sol".

Comment: @Centaurus, "jiló" ser metáfora para 'amargor' faz todo o sentido. Eu tinha pensado algo do tipo "a enxada e a foice foram os brinquedos da minha infância", em que "brinquedos" é usado ironicamente; portanto com "jiló" sendo também irónico; mas "jiló da vida" = "amargor da vida" é muito mais direto e faz sentido. Eu pensei na possibilidade de "a sol" ser "sob o sol"; mas creio que mesmo no Brasil o corrente é "ao sol"? Mas tu ouves a Elis Regina cantar "a só",  e eu tenho mais confiança nos teus ouvidos que nos meus nestes casos. Embora outros, presumivelmente brasileiros, ouvissem "a sol".

Comment: @Centaurus, onde creio que não há dúvida é que é "E de [...] gibeira o jiló", e não do "É de [...] gibeira ou jiló"? Falta-no então o raio da "gibeira". Voltando ao jiló, cheguei a pensar que as pessoas se pudessem enfeitar com a flor do jiló; então o laço, nó, e gibeira, presumivelmente todos instrumentos de trabalho, seriam o enfeite dele.

Comment: Quando falamos em jiló, a maioria das pessoas torce o nariz.  Não sei se é um fruto conhecido em Portugal mas, pelas bandas de cá, o jiló tem poucos admiradores.  E é amargo.

Comment: Pois eu acho que eu estava errado e tu estavas certo.  Ouvindo de novo a Elis, eu entendi "sol".  Além disso, o cenário do vídeo acompanha a música e quando é cantada a palavra jiló, aparece um jiló.  Quando fala-se do nó, aparece um nó.  E quando ela canta só/sol  aparece um cenário de terra árida e possivelmente quente.

Comment: Gibeira é uma corruptela de algibeira e dá origem à palavra gibão, usada no Nordeste do Brasil.

Comment: Encontrei [este artigo](https://www.revistas.usp.br/significacao/article/view/65649) de uma linguista analisando a canção semioticamente, talvez seja de ajuda. (E, na transcrição dela, é *"a Sol"*; não *"a só"*). Este é um clássico da música caipira, gênero pelo qual sou apaixonado.

Comment: Laço, nesse contexto, é mais provável que se refira à [corda usada para imobilizar e capturar gado](http://www.aulete.com.br/la%C3%A7o).

Comment: @Seninha, obrigado pelo artigo (ainda não li); também pensei que fosse esse o laço.

Comment: @Centaurus, pronto volto ao "a sol" na canção da Elis. Não sei se "a sol" é corrente algures no Brasil, mas pode simplesmente ser liberdade artística: "vida cumprida a sol" sugere-me uma vida árdua "ao sol" e "de sol a sol"; "ao sol" é mais vezes apreciativo ("lugar ao sol), mas "de sol a sol" conota normalmente trabalho duro. Pois, quanto ao jiló é provavelmente isso mesmo, simplesmente 'ardor'.

Comment: @Ailton, sim o Priberam também diz que *gibeira* vem de *algibeira*, e é lógico. Mas não me parece que seja um algibeira comum. Toda a gente tem algibeiras na roupa; na canção deve ser algo típico daquele modo de vida, como o laço e o nó. Parece é não estar relacionado com *gibão*; *gibão* já veio de Portugal; segundo o Houaiss está atestado no século XV, e vem do italiano antigo *gippone*, atualmente *giubbone*.

Comment: @Jacinto Algibeira também pode ser, para além de um bolso, um «[2.](https://dicionario.priberam.org/algibeira) pequeno saco ou bolsa usado atado à cintura ou por dentro da roupa.» Creio que isto explica bem a gibeira, não?

Comment: @Centaurus não, o jiló não é conhecido por cá; pelo menos eu nunca ouvi dele. ([Ethiopian eggplant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_eggplant)... que curioso.)

Comment: Jacinto, creio que podemos omitir o artido definido "o" em "ao" e ao invés de dizermos "ao sol", podemos usar só a preposição e dizer "a sol", sem mudar o significado e sem ferir a gramática.  Só não é idiomático, mas não afasto a possibilidade de que o seja em algum ponto do interior desse Brasil imenso.

Comment: @ANeves, poderá ser isso; um saco atado à cintura seria mais digno de nota que um simples bolso. Eu nunca ouvi chamar *algibeira* a nada que não fosse um bolso; aqui em Portugal essa aceção 'saco' deve ser coisa que já não se usa, ou então regionalismo. Não estou 100% seguro que o Probiram tenha dado todas as aceções de *gibeira*, especialmente as de culturas regionais, e eles dão essa aceção não diretamente em *gibeira*, mas via *algibeira*; alguém deverá conseguir confirmar diretamente o que raio é a tal gibeira do caipira. Mas parece-me que deve ser qualquer coisa distintiva e visível.

Comment: Sim, eu também nunca ouvi algibeira como "bolso-solto". Mas vem de «árabe al-jibairâ, pequeno saco», e esse significado pode ter persistido em alguma zona do país. Concordo com essa tua leitura.

Answer (score 3):

É de sonho e de pó,
o destino de um só.
Feito eu perdido em pensamentos
Sobre o meu cavalo.
É de laço e de nó, de **gibeira**, **o jiló**
dessa vida cumprida a sól.  -------------------Renato Teixeira.

Sendo o jiló um fruto amargo e que não agrada à maioria das pessoas, "o jiló dessa vida" é a metáfora para "o sofrimento, o amargor". E, trabalhando no campo, de sol a sol, a vida desse camponês a isso se resume: laços, nós, gibeira/bolso (onde possivelmente se estabeleceu o jiló)  O que encontrei na literatura a respeito foi o seguinte:

> - o sujeito está perdido, sem rumo, e, embora
>     consiga fazer algumas ações, elas não o conduzem a nada
>     proveitoso e se encontram como que automatizadas: embora cavalgue,
>     dê laços e nós, guarde algo na gibeira, o "eu?' permanece "perdido
>     em pensamentos", tendo como destino apenas o sofrimento (o **"jiló
>     dessa vida"**) e o nada (**"é de pó"**).**1**
> - "Às vezes somos laçados pelo destino a viver toda uma vida num só lugar, como atado por um nó."**2**
> - "Renato Teixeira fala da luta cansativa do viver camponês, uma carga da pesada e deveras amarga, como o fruto do jiloeiro.**2**"
> - "Passando para a segunda estrofe, o sujeito conta sua história
>     pregressa. Seu "pai foi peão", portanto, além de figura ausente na
>     família, também um que cumpriu a vida a Sol."**1**
> - "A "mãe, solidão". A
>     poesia desse verso, em que nem o verbo "ser" está presente (o "foi"
>     encontra-se elipsado) traz toda a fragilidade e tristeza em que viveu
>     essa mãe. Enquanto o pai é caracterizado por sua atividade profissional,
>     a mãe é um sentimento. Sozinha pela ausência do marido, criando os
>     filhos, certamente também cumprindo a vida a Sol."**1**
>
>   1. [**https://bollog.wordpress.com/2013/03/15/elis-regina/**](https://bollog.wordpress.com/2013/03/15/elis-regina/)
>   2. [**https://www.revistas.usp.br/significacao/article/download/65649/68264**](https://www.revistas.usp.br/significacao/article/download/65649/68264)

Comment: Sim, creio que quanto ao jiló e ao "a sol" (no blog sobre a Elis está "a só"! lol) estamos decididos. Eu ainda gostava de ver essa "gibeira". Li também o artigo da USP, mas a autora dá o significado literal de "gibeira", como de tudo o resto, como sabido. No outro site dizem que é um bolso, mas bolsos tenho eu quatro só nas minhas calças! Deve ser uma bolsa ou sacola exterior que os dicionários dizem que "algibeira" pode ser.

Answer (score 2):

Penso que encontrei o sentido real da letra da música, pelo menos no que se refere à sua primeira estrofe.

É de sonho e de pó o destino de um só, /
Feito eu — perdido em pensamentos sobre o meu cavalo —; /
É de laço e de nó de gibeira o jiló /
Dessa vida — cumprida a sol.

Se fôssemos colocar em sintaxe regular, poderíamos escrever da seguinte forma: O destino de um só é feito de sonho e de pó, feito o meu destino, pois estou perdido em pensamentos (sonhos) e estou sobre o meu cavalo. O jiló dessa vida (que é cumprida, realizada, a sol — quer dizer, o modo de realizá-la é "sol", ou trabalhando muito ao sol) é ligado a ela (à vida) de laço e de nó de gibeira.

A mim é muito claro que ele está não elencando coisas: laço, nó, gibeira, jiló, e sim construindo uma frase do mesmo tipo da primeira, em que como que se define algo. A amargura dessa vida como que lhe é constitucional, ela é de laço e de nó de gibeira. Não me parece certo de forma alguma separar "nó" de "de gibeira", pois a entonação que Renato Teixeira dá a essa parte leva-nos a entender que ele está falando de um nó específico: o nó de gibeira. A amargura está muito bem amarrada a essa vida.

A minha interpretação da música está de acordo com os trechos do trabalho da USP aqui publicados, com a entonação específica que o cantor dá a ela e enfim à história contada. Trata-se de um caipira que percebe que no final das contas está sozinho e que sente uma amargura nessa vida solitária. Ele então recorre a uma peregrinação até a cidade de Aparecida, para a romaria. Embora não saiba rezar, oferece à Nossa Senhora um olhar sincero, sinceríssimo, pois vem de um homem que se reconhece simples (portanto não tem nada a afetar) e que sente uma solidão amarga; vem, enfim, de um homem com o coração nas mãos.

Comment: Josué, obrigado pela tua contribuição. Concordo com a interpretação de "alto nível": o caipira teve um vida solitária, dura e amarga. A minha pergunta é sobre a interpretação de "baixo nível": o que é exatamente a "gibeira"? Se é simplesmente uma algibeira, bolso normais, eu neste momento tenho duas nos meus calções, e porque aqui é verão; no inverno, entre calças, casaco e camisa, chego a ter dez. A gibeira do caipira deve ser especial, diferente do bolso dos meu calções, não? Eu sempre ouvi "é de laço e de nó, de gibeira, o giló" ou seja, "o giló é de laço, de nó e de gibeira" >>

Comment: >> mas a tua interpretação--"o giló é de laço e de nó de gibeira"--parece-me interessante. E que seria então o nó da gibeira? Aí é que a gibeira tem mesmo de ser diferente de uma algibeira normal; as minhas algibeiras não têm nó nenhum. (Aqui em Portugal, "algibeira" tem caído em desuso. Mas o meu pai, homem do campo, falava da preferencialmente de "algibeira das calças" e não "bolso das calças".)

Answer (score 1):

Esclarecendo alguns pontos:

Em primeiro lugar, a letra da música compara o que o peão, um sertanejo, carrega com a vida em si.

Porque peão "sertanejo"? Aí entra a "gibeira". Gibeira é o mesmo que algibeira, ou bolso, o do paletó. Os peões sertanejos usam um casaco, similar a um paletó, feito de couro duro, o gibão, que serve como escudo contra os espinhos da vegetação característica do sertão.

"É de sonho e de pó, o destino de um só". Não é "o destino de apenas um", e sim, o destino de um solitário.

Todos estamos intimamente sós, e o peão tem isso em conta.

O "sonho" é a perspectiva de uma vida diferente. "Pó" pode ser o dos caminhos da terra ou a matéria em que resultam os sonhos, os dois, talvez. Podem, ainda, haver outras interpretações, mas não me parece importante escolher qualquer uma.

"É de laço e de nó"

O laço e o nó servem, aqui, tanto como ferramentas distintivas da profissão de peão, como alude à condição de estar atado à essa vida.

"De gibeira, o jiló"

É a frase correta, já que é a única que faz sentido. De gibeira, viaja o jiló.

Jiló, claro, como já disseram, é um fruto amargo, muito apreciado no nordeste brasileiro, uma alusão ao amargor da vida do peão, o sofrimento.

"Dessa vida cumprida a sol". Não é "a só".

O peão sertanejo não vive, num sentido lato. Ele cumpre a vida à qual está atado, sem outras perspectivas tangíveis, como se viver fosse uma tarefa, e uma da qual não pode escapar.

O peão, então, cumpre a vida trabalhando a descoberto, sob o sol. O sertão é semi-desértico, e quase nunca vê chuva.

Espero ter ajudado, tanto quanto agradeço a oportunidade!

Answer (score 1):

Quando garôto, ouvi e ví diversas vêzes em Minas, cavaleiros comuns sem o gibão sôbre cavalos ou mulas, burros, referirem-se à gibeira, mas não ví nenhum paletó de couro, mas tipos de bolsões.Observei que para prender certos utensílhos , davam muitos laços e nós, curioso é que após ouvir a música, notei que onde o peão firma o pé, o estribo tem a forma de giló e alguns dêles os vi com um giló à boca. Mas eu particularmente interpreto "a só", já que êle descasou e se fizesse referência ao astro, seria "ao sol" na cavalgada pelas estradas,os ví sempre solitários, e na parte que diz cumprida, precisa certificar se é comprida (referindo-se à extensão longa dessa vida),ou cumprida, igual missão amarga.Tanto de um como de outro modo é aceitável e belo.Sim, solitário êle é: sem pai, sem mãe, sem os irmãos e descasado, solitário e mudo até em sua oração. Dizendo estas palavras, posso talvez até ter contrariado o autor, mas vivemos em um mundo poético.

Comment: Olá Joaquim, sugiro que tente editar a sua essa resposta de modo a ser mais objetivo e responder mais diretamente àquilo que foi perguntado

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

É muito simples a interpretação deste verso: “de gibeira o jiló” significa que ele carrega o amargor, o sofrimento com ele.

Comment: Bem-vinda ao Portuguese Language! Poder dar mais detalhes e/ou adicionar alguma fonte que confirme o que disse?